# How to load a link from external page in same div

Tags: php, jquery

Need help..

I have an `index.php` page. On that page, I have a link to `page-2.php`.

On `page-2.php`,

i also have a link to other page. May I know how to load the link on `page-2.php` in a same div on `index.php` page.

I'm using jQuery load method do to this. I'm able to load `page-2.php` inside a `div` on `index.php`. Below are the codes that I made.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('a#staff_info').click(function(e){ //link to page-2.php
  e.preventDefault();
  var page = $(this).attr('href');
  $('#content').load(page);
  $('a#upd_staff').click(function(){ //link on page2.php 
     var page_info = $('a#upd_staff').attr('href');
     $('#content').load(page_info);
  });   
 }); 
});
```

the above code will direct me to a new page not on a same div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ajax is asynchronous.

> ```
> $('#content').load(page);
> ```

The above starts loading page two

> ```
> $('a#upd_staff').click(function(){ //link on page2.php
> ```

Then you try to bind your event handler to content from page 2 *before* it is has finished loading.

So when you click on the link, there is no JS bound to it, so it acts as a normal link.

---

Use deferred event handlers (so they listen on the document and check what element was clicked when the click happens).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function ajaxLoad(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var page = $(this).attr('href');
        $('#content').load(page);       
    }
    $(document).on("click", "a#staff_info, a#upd_staff", ajaxLoad);
 });
```

Comment: Thanks @quentin.will try it

Comment: it's working great.. thanks for the help guys. Credits to Quentin!

Answer (score 0):

when you click on `$('a#staff_info')` this -- I can see that you use `e.preventDefault();` for preventing the normal action of the anchor tag but when you click on `$('a#upd_staff')` this you did not use `e.preventDefault();` -- that's why this redirect to `page2.php`. Use `e.preventDefault();` - this for next one click may be this will help you

Comment: try to use `e.preventDefault();`  but still direct me to a new page not on a same `div`

Answer (score -1):

You can use `get()` for add directly on your div:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('a#staff_info').click(function(e){ //link to page-2.php
  e.preventDefault();
  var page = $(this).attr('href');
  $.get(page, function(data, status){
    //action on page loaded, data is your page result
     $('#content').html(data)
  });
  $('a#upd_staff').click(function(){ //link on page2.php 
     var page_info = $('a#upd_staff').attr('href');
     $('#content').load(page_info);
  });   
 }); 
});
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. You are still binding the event handler while the content is loading. You're just using a more verbose approach to loading that content.

Comment: yes, he issue is the page load to new page, not on a div *"the above code will direct me to a new page not on a same div"*. My approach load the content into a div. Is correct and work fine. peraps is no the best way but it's work